# Наезд div блоков друг на друга

Tags: html, css

В мобильной версии Safari мой `<div>` блок футера наползает на другие элементы(см. фото), как я только ни пытался его сделать. И через `HTML`, и через `CSS`, все равно наползает. Как это можно исправить? Чтобы, если начинает наползать, то появлялся скроллинг и они не перемешивались[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.erm {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.copyright {
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
  color: #424242;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.round {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

.icon-social {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.social {
  width: 248px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 430px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.sur-name {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 330px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.dev {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 370px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #afafaf;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>MySite</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/browser_icon.png" type="image/png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers|Orbitron:900" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <img src="images/erm.png" class="erm">
  <img src="images/photo.png" class="round">
  <div class="sur-name">My name</div>
  <div class="dev">information</div>
  <div class="social">
    <a href="javascript:PopUpShow()"><img src="images/email.png" class="icon-social"></a>
    <a href="https://vk.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/vk.png" class="icon-social"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/instagram.png" class="icon-social"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="copyright">Copyright © 2017 All rights reserved</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: попробуйте уменьшить top-ы у всех вышестоящих элементов, какой экран у вашего тестового устройства?

Comment: @CoffeJava, iphone 5S, 640x1136

Comment: Ваш код попробовал на симуляторе мобильного браузера  и на реальном устройстве (правда не на ябокофоне), уменьшив top-ы получил весьма приличный результат. И если Ваша страница не будет динамически наполняемой (комментарии и т.д.) то это самый простой вариант. ИМХО :)